# "The client is unauthorized due to authentication failure"

Tags: neo4j

I just started to learn Neo4j.However, I come across a problem when connecting to Neo4j at the very beginning. As the image shown, it says "The client is unauthorized due to authentication failure." Any solutions?

[image: My browser shows this]

Comment: Default user name: `neo4j`, default password: `neo4j` :)

Comment: what do you do when it's the neo4j credential that is locked out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the command line, there is same situation. Give username and pass as argument. Like:

```
-u neo4j -p neo4j
```

Comment: From where to use the command line in Neo4j?

Answer (score 3):

Since the accepted answer made no sense to me, here's my answer.
Im using Neo4J Community Server 4.4.8 and when you download it, you get a folder that looks something like this

[image: Neo4J Community Server Folder]

Look into the `Neo4J Community Server Folder/data` and the folder looks like this and DELETE the inside of databases and transactions
[image: data folder]

DELETE this in `data/databases`
[image: data/databases]

DELETE this in `data/transactions`
[image]

**NOTES**

1. After you delete this the file in your databases will gone
2. This is works if you're working in localhost
3. After you delete all that, the neo4j in `localhost:7474` will be reset with `USERNAME = neo4j` and `PASSWORD = neo4j`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. After trying many things, I solved it by creating a new user with **admin** and **PUBLIC** roles from browser. Then used this username and password in my application:

```
spring.neo4j.uri=bolt://localhost:7687
spring.neo4j.authentication.username=myuser
spring.neo4j.authentication.password=mypass
```

I attach the images:

[image]

--- then ---

[image]

--- then ---

[image]